# how to send web push to all users in database?

Tags: javascript, php, web-push

I'm trying to build an simple broadcast messaging menu. In that admin should be able to send notifications to his users. This code will send web push to selected user. But I want to send notification to all users in the database. What I have to change here?

> broadcast.php

```
     <?php SESSION_START(); include "isLogin.php"; include "dbconn.php"; include "sql.php"; $sql = new sql(); 
     $user = $sql->listUser();
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <title>Broadcast Menu</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <center><div class = "boxed">
     <h2>Simple Broadcast Message Menu</h2>

     <a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

    <hr>

    <form method="post"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
     ">

    <table>

    <tr>

    <td>Message</td>

    <td><textarea name="msg" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td>Broadcast time</td>

    <td><select name="time"><option>Now</option></select> </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Loop</td>

    <td><select name="loops">
    <?php 
     for ($i=1; $i<=5 ; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select> time</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

    <td>Loop Every</td>

    <td><select name="loop_every">
    <?php 
    for ($i=1; $i<=60 ; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>Minute</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>For</td>

    <td><select name="user" id="user">
    <?php foreach ($user[1] as $key) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key['username'] ?>"><?php echo $key['username'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
    <hr>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td><button name="submit" type="submit">Broadcast </button></td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    </form>

    <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { if(isset($_POST['msg']) and isset($_POST['time']) and 
    isset($_POST['loops']) and isset($_POST['loop_every']) and isset($_POST['user'])) { $msg = 
    $_POST['msg']; 
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); $loop= $_POST['loops']; $loop_every=$_POST['loop_every']; $user = 
    $_POST['user']; /*save Notification*/ $save = $sql>saveNotif($msg,$time,$loop,$loop_every,$user);
   if($save[0] == true)
     {
    echo '* save new notification success';
   }else{
   echo 'error save data : '.$save[1];
   }

   }else{
   echo '* completed the parameter above';
   }
   } 
   ?>
   <table border=1>

   <thead>

   <tr>

  <td>No</td>


  <td>Next Schedule</td>


  <td>Message</td>


    <td>Remains</td>


  <td>User</td>

  </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php $a =1; $list = $sql->listNotif();
  foreach ($list[1] as $key) {
  ?>

  <tr>

  <td><?php echo $a ?></td>


  <td><?php echo $key['notif_time'] ?></td>


  <td><?php echo $key['notif_msg'] ?></td>


 <td><?php echo $key['notif_loop']; ?></td>


 <td><?php echo $key['username'] ?></td>

  </tr>

 <?php $a++; } ?>
 </tbody>

 </table>

 </body>
 <style>
 .boxed{
 width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
 padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
 }
 </style>
 </html>
```

> ajax.php

```
  <?php SESSION_START(); 
  include "isLogin.php"; 
  include "dbconn.php"; 
  include "sql.php"; 
  $sql = new sql(); 
  $array=array(); 
  $rows=array(); 
  $listnotif = $sql->listNotifUser($_SESSION['username']);
  foreach ($listnotif[1] as $key) {
  $data['title'] = 'From admin';
  $data['msg'] = $key['notif_msg'];
  $data['icon'] = 'http://localhost/notification/avatar2.png';
  $data['url'] = 'https://cbra.co.in';
  $rows[] = $data;
  // update notification database
  $nextime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))+($key['notif_repeat']*60));
  $sql->updateNotif($key['id'],$nextime);
  }
  $array['notif'] = $rows;
  $array['count'] = $listnotif[2];
  $array['result'] = $listnotif[0];
  echo json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

> mynotif.js

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   checknotif();
   setInterval(function(){ checknotif(); }, 10000);
   });
   function checknotif() {
   if (!Notification) {
   $('body').append(' <h4 style="color:red">*Browser does not support Web Notification</h4>');
   return;
   }
   if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
   Notification.requestPermission();
   else {
   $.ajax(
   {
   url : "ajax.php",
   type: "POST",
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
   {
   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   if(data.result == true){
   var data_notif = data.notif;

   for (var i = data_notif.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   var theurl = data_notif[i]['url'];
   var notifi = new Notification(data_notif[i]['title'], {
   icon: data_notif[i]['icon'],
   body: data_notif[i]['msg'],
   });
   notifi.onclick = function () {
   window.open(theurl); 
   notifi.close();     
   };
   setTimeout(function(){
   notifi.close();
   }, 5000);
   };
   }else{

   }
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
   {

   }
   }); 

   }
   };
```

> database table

```
 username password
 ronaldo  123
 admin    admin
 nila     123
 shobi    123
```

waiting for help. Please help me to send web push to all users in the database

Comment: Simple update is you can have change user select box into checkboxes and loop for the selected value to be inserted.

Comment: @SKos I've changed the for section like this                                                                         <td>For

<br><?php foreach ($user[1] as $key) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" id="user" name="user" value="<?php echo $key['username'] ?>"><?php echo $key['username'] ?>
<label for="user"></label><br>
<?php } ?>
</td>                                                                                                                                     If i selected more than one person it sends notification the last selected person           What I've to do now

Answer (score 0):

for more detail copy saveNotif and listNotifUser functions from sql.php file.

as I found, ajax.php code read selected user from SESSION. if you knew how to code in php you can select all users by mysql query and send notification to all users by using foreach loop.